# Visual Studio could not find part of the path for .signature.p7s

Tags: visual-studio-2019, elmah.mvc

When I try to check in to TFS through Visual Studio 2019, I'm getting this message:

> D:\Source\Suburban\Web
> Projects\WebPortalSite\packages\elmah.1.2.signature.p7s: Could not
> find a part of the path 'D:\Source\Suburban\Web
> Projects\WebPortalSite\packages\elmah.1.2.signature.p7s'.

I checked for the file and the elmah folder doesn't exist for that version, only the elmah.1.2.2.

[image]

I did a search in my solution for elmah.1.2 and didn't find anything.

I tried to reinstall the Nuget packages with the command but it did nto resolve the issue:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

I've no idea how to resolve this, any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't be committing packages to source control in the first place. Add `packages` to your `.gitignore` or `.tfignore` and ensure the `packages` directory is deleted from source control as well.

Comment: @DanielMann Thanks for the response. I didn't add them, I suppose the Nuget manager did. Should I exclude the entire packages directory from checking in?

Comment: Yes, the entire `packages` folder should be excluded from version control via your `.gitignore` / `.tfignore`.